# Проблема с доступом к файлу .env на хостинге с Apache

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

Разработал сайт на локальной машине в среде **Homestead** на фреймворке Laravel 5. В корневом каталоге как положено находится **.env** c настройками. Все хорошо работает.
Залил сайт на хостинг c сервером Apache. Соответственно, в корневой каталог добавил **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Сайт открывается, но данные из **.env** не читаются. Это видно по тому, что laravel-приложение использует значения переменных окружения по умолчанию. Например, в файле **config/app.php** прописано:

```
...
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString'),
...
```

а в файле **.env**:

```
...
APP_KEY=T8kjTyRamRXtxNBRbrpgAt45d0uiH95F
...
```

в итоге laravel-приложение использует значение *'SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString'*.

Подскажите, в чем проблема? Почему данные с .env не читаются на сервере Apache?

Comment: Не совсем понял: данные из .env не читаются, но при этом используются те значения, которые указаны в этом файле? "SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString" ведь в env определен и именно это значение и используется. Вы может хотели написать "не использует значение"? И как вы пытаетесь его получить? [getenv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getenv.php) пробовали?

Comment: И судя по [докам](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration) файл должен иметь имя `.env.php`

Comment: Прошу прощения, в вопросе я перепутал файлы config/app.php и .env. Теперь исправил...

Comment: @BOPOH обратите внимание, что в вопросе указана версия фреймворка 5, а вы даете ссылку на документацию по версии 4.2

Comment: Это моя оплошность. Версию Фреймворка я уточнил уже после того, как ВОРОН написал комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден. Необходимо было в конфигурации PHP на хостинге включить функцию `putenv()`, которая была по умолчанию отключена.